# Sync a label with angular.js video player's progress time

Tags: angularjs, html, video, html5-video

I have a web page that consist a video and a  label that shows a series of data about certain parts of the video. for example  while the video is played, in 10'th and 18'th second of the video , the label must be updated automatically. i can not use a separate timer because some parameters such as  slow internet connection can make synchronization.  Is there any way/ any component that can solve this issue?

Comment: Never used it, but the documentation indicates that there is a timeupdate even that is fired when the currentTime of the video changes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate